# javascript import always returning import declaration error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to import a class but it always returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module.` This is the first time that I had to create my own class to properly implement a maintainable module/functionality in an app I'm trying to make. I didn't really have any problems when using other libraries before, so I'm somewhat confused on what I'm doing wrong.

NOTE: I'm not using nodejs/vuejs or any other framework. Just pure/vanilla JS

scripts (these are the only scripts being used in the page I'm testing)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{{ asset('js/img_mapper/controller/img_map_controller.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/img_mapper/img_map.js') }}"></script>
```

img_map.js

```
import {ImgMapController} from "./controller/img_map_controller";

$(document).ready(function () {
    ImgMapController.disableContextMenu();
});
```

img_map_controller.js

```
export default class ImgMapController {
    static disableContextMenu(element = $('.img-map')) {
        element.on('contextmenu', () => false);
    }
}
```

Comment: add `type="module"` to `img_map.js` script tag and leave controller file to be loaded by this module (don't write separate script tag for itj, just make sure the path matches)

Comment: Yikes. So that's all it had to be to make it work. Just wondering why it had to be 'module'? Is it required because I used import that it had to be module?

Comment: You can make an answer so I can properly tag it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `type="module"` to `img_map.js` script tag and leave controller file to be loaded by this module (don't write separate script tag for itj, just make sure the path matches).

[why we need modules in javascript](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/)